# Mixing Objective C and C in switch statement trying to add a subview iphone SDK

Tags: iphone, c, objective-c, loops, subview

I'm experiencing a weird problem. I have a for loop, inside the loop there is a switch statement. The counter in the for loop is a pointer that points to the beginning of a primitive array, it increments itself till it finds a "terminator number". The array pointed is used to build a view, each elements represent a subview to put in the view.
Here is the code:

```
    for (self.composizione; *composizione>kFine; composizione++) {
    int c=(int)*composizione;
    NSLog(@"%d",c);
    switch (c) {
        case kForchettaPesce:   case kForchettaNormale:
        {
            NSString *imagePath;
            imagePath=[[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%@/%d.png",[[NSBundle mainBundle]resourcePath],c];
            UIImage *image=[[UIImage alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:imagePath];
            [imagePath release];
            NSLog(@"pippo");
            UIImageView *imageView=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, image.size.width, image.size.height)];
            imageView.image=image;
            [image release];
            [self.view addSubview:imageView];
            [imageView release];

        break;
        }


        default:
        break;
    }
    NSLog(@"%d",(int)*composizione);



}
```

Debugging it I've found out that works perfectly untill it tries to add the subview. It seems to stay stucked in the loop and the log shows always the same datas in an infinite cycle. If I delete the -addSubview method I have no problem, the log statement shows what I expect to see.
What am I doing wrong?
Regards,
Andrea

Comment: I got to say I have no clue why it doesn't work. How about trying to create your own array and add to views you create to the array. After the for loop is complete add the views in your array to the superview. It might give us a clue.

Comment: BTW you may consider using english in your code. Easier to understand for other people.

Comment: Thanks Ron I've pointed the error, I was using it in loadView method. I'm using a nib so I delete it and copied into viewDidLoad, everything is working now.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you are trying to do, but it may be that you're kind of mixing up your types:

```
for (self.composizione; *composizione>kFine; composizione++) {
    int c=(int)*composizione;
```

- the `self.composizione` after `for(` is redundant, it doesn't do anything. Should it?
- `*composizione` is the value pointed to by `composizione`, which should be an `int*` (is it?)
- `composizione++` advances the *pointer* to the next location in memory, not the *value* of `*composizione`

in short: maybe you need a `(*composizione)++` instead of `composizione++`.

Comment: Hello mvds, I appreciate your suggestions. Sorry for the italian part in my code, but I forgot to translate.
1°yes self.composizione is redudant, but i use for better reading|||

2°yes, almost :-) in the reality is a pointer to a typedef enum|||

3°right! I'm scrolling an array so it must increment the pointer, not the value|||


Thanks anyway, but the solution was easier (as always).I was using that chunk of code in -loadView method that is not correct for view initialized in nib. I'm using a nib so I delete it and copied into viewDidLoad, everything is working now.

Comment: Good that you solved it. You may consider writing it in such a way, that it is a little more self-explanatory. I.e. `for(int i=0;comp[i]!=kLast;i++) { }`. Especially if other people need to read it.